# How to correctly remove NUnit3TestAdapter from csproj project file

Tags: c#, nunit, csproj

I changed the unit testing of a C# test project from NUnit to xUnit. I already removed the NUnit nuget package. But when I look into the csproj file there still the NUnit3TestAdapter is there:

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\..\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.10.0\build\net35\NUnit3TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.10.0\build\net35\NUnit3TestAdapter.props')" />
...
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\..\..\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.10.0\build\net35\NUnit3TestAdapter.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\..\..\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.10.0\build\net35\NUnit3TestAdapter.props'))" />
```

I dont see this in the nuget package manager.

So my question: How to remove this correctly? Should I edit the file manually or is there a way to remove it with VS2017?

**Edit:** I removed these two lines manually from csproj file. It seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually edit your `.csproj` file and remove unused references. Just be sure to save an old copy in case you accidentally corrupt the XML.

You might also want to check your `packages` folder and make sure the package folder is removed, in addition to checking `packages.config` file and making sure the reference is removed there too.

Comment: But only remove it from packages folder if it's not used by other projects in the solution(s)

Comment: Correct. You will see an error message for unresolved package references. So be sure that your projects are not referencing any before you remove.